# Using same fragment for different user information with SessionInfo

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I wonder if anyone can help, I made this Android Studio project which has a MainActivity, 4 Fragments, a class list type called TestList, another class to save the information session called SessionInfo and personalized ArrayAdapter called MyCustomArrayAdapter.

Firstly, I want the program use the DetailUserFragment to display the user information, and this same fragment works to deploy different info for each user, depending on which user is selected in the list information

Secondly, Selecting a user from the list should expand the corresponding user information, using the same info from the SessionInfo.java

This is the MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startNewFragment(new Fragment1());
}

public void startNewFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    // Initialize fragment transaction
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    // Replace with fragment content
    ft.replace(R.id.main_frame, fragment);
    // Animation on change
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    // Clear stack (back button memory)
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}

public void setActionBarTitle(String title) {
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
}
}
```

The UserListFragment.java

```
public class UserListFragment extends Fragment {

public ListView lista;
protected SessionInfo session = null;

public UserListFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Indicates fragment has menu
    this.setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_list_layout, container, false);
    session = SessionInfo.getInstance();

    lista = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView_secondFragment);

    // Construct the data source
    ArrayList<TestList> arrayOfUsers = session.getTestList();

    //test user for be beginning
    if (arrayOfUsers.isEmpty()) {
        TestList newUser = new TestList(1, "Prueba", "30", "San José");
        session.getTestList().add(newUser);
    }

    // Create the adapter to convert the array to views
    MyCustomArrayAdapter adapter = new MyCustomArrayAdapter(getActivity(), arrayOfUsers);
    // Attach the adapter to a ListView
    lista.setAdapter(adapter);

    lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            int itemPosition = position;

            if (itemPosition == 0){
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).startNewFragment(new DetailUserFragment());
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "no posee detalle", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_opt_location) {
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).startNewFragment(new NewUserFragment());
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.list_items, menu);
}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setActionBarTitle(getString(R.string.fragment_title_2));
}
}
```

The NewUserFragment.java

```
public class NewUserFragment extends Fragment {

public TextView text_name;
public TextView text_age;
public TextView text_hometown;
public EditText edit_text_name;
public EditText edit_text_age;
public EditText edit_text_hometown;
public Button fill_button;

public Random random = new Random();
protected SessionInfo session = null;

protected String name;
protected String age;
protected String hometown;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_user_layout, container, false);

    session = SessionInfo.getInstance();

    text_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_name);
    text_age = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_age);
    text_hometown = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_hometown);

    edit_text_name = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_name);
    edit_text_age = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_age);
    edit_text_hometown = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_hometown);

    fill_button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.fill_button);

    fill_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            name = edit_text_name.getText().toString();
            age = edit_text_age.getText().toString();
            hometown = edit_text_hometown.getText().toString();

            if (name.matches("") | age.matches("") | hometown.matches("")) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Por favor complete el formulario", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {

                //Random number for the icon
                int icon = random.nextInt(5 - 1) + 1;

                // Add item to adapter
                TestList newUser = new TestList(icon, name, age, hometown);
                session.getTestList().add(newUser);

                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).startNewFragment(new UserListFragment());
            }
        }
    });

    return view;
}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setActionBarTitle(getString(R.string.fragment_title_4));
}
}
```

The DetailUserFragment.java

```
public class DetailUserFragment extends Fragment {

public ImageView icon_detail_layout = null;
public TextView detail_name = null;
public TextView detail_age = null;
public TextView detail_hometown = null;
public TestList test_list;

protected SessionInfo session = null;

public DetailUserFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_user_layout, container, false);

    session = SessionInfo.getInstance();

    icon_detail_layout = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon_detail_layout);
    detail_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detail_name);
    detail_age = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detail_age);
    detail_hometown = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detail_hometown);

    return view;
}

private void setPersonData() {

    if (!test_list.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.EMPTY_STRING)) {
        this.detail_name.setText(getString(R.string.name, this.test_list.getName()));
        this.detail_name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    if (!test_list.getAge().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.EMPTY_STRING)) {
        this.detail_age.setText(getString(R.string.age, this.test_list.getAge()));
        this.detail_age.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    if (!test_list.getHometown().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.EMPTY_STRING)) {
        this.detail_hometown.setText(getString(R.string.hometown, this.test_list.getHometown()));
        this.detail_hometown.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setActionBarTitle(getString(R.string.fragment_title_3));
//        setPersonData();
}
}
```

The SessionInfo.java

```
public class SessionInfo {

public static final int selected_user = -1;

private SessionInfo() {
    super();
    test_list = new ArrayList<TestList>();
    this.setTestList(null);
}

public static SessionInfo instance = null;
public static SessionInfo getInstance() {
    if (SessionInfo.instance == null) { SessionInfo.instance = new SessionInfo(); }
    return SessionInfo.instance;
}

public static void endInstance() { SessionInfo.instance = null; }

private ArrayList<TestList> test_list;
public ArrayList<TestList> getTestList() { return this.test_list; }
public void setTestList(ArrayList<TestList> list) {this.test_list = (list != null) ? list : new ArrayList<TestList>(); }
}
```

TestList.java

```
public class TestList {

public TestList() {
    this.setName(null);
    this.setAge(null);
    this.setHometown(null);
}

public TestList (int imageID, String name, String age, String hometown) {
    super();
    this.setImageID(imageID);
    this.setName(name);
    this.setAge(age);
    this.setHometown(hometown);
}

private int imageID;
public int getImageID() { return imageID; }
public void setImageID(int value) { this.imageID = value; }

private String name;
public String getName() { return name; }
public void setName(String value) { this.name = (value != null) ? value : Constants.EMPTY_STRING; }

private String age;
public String getAge() { return age; }
public void setAge(String value) { this.age = (value != null) ? value : Constants.EMPTY_STRING; }

private String hometown;
public String getHometown() { return hometown; }
public void setHometown(String value) { this.hometown = (value != null) ? value : Constants.EMPTY_STRING; }
}
```

and MyCustomArrayAdapter.java

```
public class MyCustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TestList>{

public MyCustomArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<TestList> testLists) {
    super(context, 0, testLists);
}

@Override
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_adapter, parent, false);
    }
    // Get the data item for this position
    TestList testList = getItem(position);

    if (testList != null) {

        // Lookup view for data population
        ImageView iconID = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iconID);
        TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        TextView tvAge = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvAge);
        TextView tvHome = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvHome);
        // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
        if (iconID != null) {
            iconID.setImageResource(setIcon(testList.getImageID()));
        }
        if (tvName != null) {
            tvName.setText("Nombre: "+testList.getName());
        }
        if (tvAge != null) {
            tvAge.setText("Edad: " + testList.getAge() +" años");
        }
        if (tvHome != null) {
            tvHome.setText("País de Origen: "+testList.getHometown());
        }
    }
    // Return the completed view to render on screen
    return convertView;
}

private int setIcon(int detail_icon) {

    switch (detail_icon) {
        case 1:
            detail_icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
            break;
        case 2:
            detail_icon = R.drawable.firefox_noshadow;
            break;
        case 3:
            detail_icon = R.drawable.example_1;
            break;
        case 4:
            detail_icon = R.drawable.example_2;
            break;
        case 5:
            detail_icon = R.drawable.example_3;
            break;
        default:
            detail_icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
            break;
    }
    return detail_icon;
}
}
```